# Wing101 - Configure python 3.3.2 from 2.7.2 on a mac

Tags: python, wing-ide

I am relatively new to programming, and I am using Wing101 version: 5.0.0-b8 (rev 29847). 
The Python Shell within Wing101, is version 2.7.2, how do I configure it to open python 3.3.2.

I have downloaded Python 3.3.2 and I need the custom Python Executable. I previously tried "/usr/bin/python" as my custom python executable, but it doesn't work.

I am on a Mac 10.8.3

Comment: What does `which python3` say? Use the result as your custom executable.

Comment: Sorry I do not understand what you mean by "which python3?". As I said I am a newbie in the field of Computer Science.

Comment: open Terminal.app and type `which python3` at the prompt that appears.

Comment: Wooble, You Are A Genius. I had no clue terminal was this smart. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location of the python.exe for Python 3.3 can vary depending on how you installed it.  Probably the best bet is to search w/ Spotlight for python.exe, press "Show All" in the drop down menu, change to "File Name" instead of "Contents" search and then click on results to see the full path at the bottom of the search results window.  You'll get at least 2-3 results and the full path should make clear which is the correct one.  Then enter that into Python Executable in the Configure Python dialog, accessed from the Source menu in Wing 101.  You'll need to restart the Python Shell in Wing 101 from its Options menu before it switches to the new Python version.

Comment: Actually the better way as indicated in part by Wooble's note above is just to run python3.3 from the command line and then do 'import sys' followed by 'sys.executable' and then use that value.  If that doesn't work because it's not on your path then you'll have to fall back to the answer above...

Comment: How do I run python3.3 from the command line? 
I typed the following code in wing101:
import sys  \n   
print sys.executable

I ran the code and it gave me a result of:
  /usr/bin/python
which I have already tried, and it does not work, I think that is the location of python 2.7.2

Comment: Thanks wingware, but I followed the which python3 and it worked like a charm.