# How do I configure Wing101 to run Python 3.3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, configuration, osx-mavericks, wing-ide

I'm taking a uni course in introductory programming, as its a requirement for continuing in astrophysics. The course is taught in Python 3.3 and they like us to use Wing101. My mac's OS is 10.9.4

I've downloaded X-11, and Python 3.3, but whenever I open Wing, it runs Python 2.7.5.

I've tried changing the executable file in the properties, and it accepts it, but when I click okay, and restart my shell, it just continues running 2.7.5

I've also looked at this question: [Wing101 - Configure python 3.3.2 from 2.7.2 on a mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19120229/wing101-configure-python-3-3-2-from-2-7-2-on-a-mac) and it hasn't helped me really.

I've no idea what to do, and it's making it really hard to do my assignments!! Any help would be awesome!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

If you can run the desired Python 3.3 outside of Wing do `import sys; print(sys.executable)`, that will give you the full path to put into the Python Executable in the Configure Python dialog (from the Edit menu).  Then restart the Python Shell from its Options menu.

Also, if you're using Wing 5 you don't need X11 on a Mac.  If you're using Wing 4 then you should try Wing 5 instead.

Answer (score 1):

Open WingIDE/
Click Source/
Choose 'show python environment'/
Click 'Change settings'/
Change Python Executable from default to Custom and choose your python3 version from the menu.